# LINQ to SQL DuplicateKeyException problem

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ2SQL and I have a table called Customers with three columns

CustmerID, CustomerCode, CustomerName

CustmerID is Primery Key(and Identity=yes) and CustomerCode is just UniqueKey.

When I am updating this table using LINQ to SQL with duplicate customercode, I expect to see DuplicateKeyException but it is going into the general exception block instead of DuplicateKeyException block. Any ideas?

This is the code

public void Update(Customer cust)
        {
            using (LINQDemoDataContext db = new LINQDemoDataContext())
            {
                Customers entity = CustomerMapper.ToEntity(new Customers(), cust);

```
            try
            {
                db.Customers.Attach(entity, true);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }

            //Concurrency Exception
            catch (ChangeConflictException)
            {                               
                throw new ChangeConflictException("A concurrency error occurred!");
            }

            //duplicate record
            catch (DuplicateKeyException)
            {
                throw new DuplicateKeyException(entity.CustmerCode);
            }

            //everything else
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using VisualWebDeveloperExpress 2008 and SQL Express 2005.

Thanks & Regards,
Supremestar

Comment: When throwing exceptions like this, I would include the original exception as the `InnerException` (use a different constructor). Also, instead of `throw ex;` in your last catch, just use `throw;`.

Comment: Or, just don't catch the last exception if you won't be handling it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But what about the DuplicateKeyException?

What about this?


catch (SqlException sqlExc)
                {
                    foreach (SqlError error in sqlExc.Errors)
                    {
                        if (error.Number == 2601)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Cannot update the Customer Record, CustomerCode must be unique");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }

Comment: @Supremestar, I think the error.Number for duplicate key would be 2627 not 2601.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, and I may be wrong here, the DuplicateKeyException only fires for the primary key of the table.

Comment: Are you sure Stephen? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: About 70% sure. If you comment out the try/catch and run it in debug, you can find out exactly which exception is getting tossed, because the IDE will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, where the duplicate key objects were being retained in-memory even though they were not getting inserted into the database. I came up with the following work around:

```
    MyDataContext _myDataContext = new MyDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    public void AddObject(object myObject)
    {
        try
        {
            _myDataContext.Objects.InsertOnSubmit(myObject);
            _myDataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException ex)
        {
            _myDataContext = new MyDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            throw ex;
```

You can then catch and handle (or ignore) the thrown DuplicateKeyException in the caller.

Another work around (albeit inefficient and memory hogging) is to create a new data context inside the AddObject method instead of using the shared data context instantiated as a class member.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem when adding an entity i got from a different DataContext.
(I bound the FooDb-Property of a BarDb-Entity to the SelectedValue from a DropDownList, which had a Table from a short-living DataContext as DataSource)
Let's look at the Linq2Sql internal Attach(entity):

```
private void attach_FooDb(FooDb entity){
    this.SendPropertyChanging();
    entity.BarDb = this;
}
```

And the BarDb Property set:

```
set{
    BarDb previousValue = this._BarDb.Entity;
    if (((previousValue != value) || (this._BarDb.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false))){
        this.SendPropertyChanging();
        if ((previousValue != null)){
            this._BarDb.Entity = null;
            previousValue.FooDb.Remove(this);
        }

        this._BarDb.Entity = value;

        if ((value != null)){
            value.FooDb.Add(this);
            this._FK_Bar = value.ID;
        }else{
            this._FK_Bar = default(System.Guid);
        }
        this.SendPropertyChanged("BarDb");
    }
}
```

So when attaching to a FooDb, the corresponding DataContext will recognize the BarDb Entity as newly created and added, even though it already existed in the Database.

You can solve it by:

- only using a single DataContext or
- creating a BarDb_safe Property in the submitting DataContext, which will first request the "equal" entity from the database, applies all properties and then attaches it the usual way.